# Real part of $\frac{1-e^{(n+1)i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I compute the real part of
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-e^{(n+1)i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}, \quad \text{where}\ \theta \in \mathbb{R}?
\end{equation*}

Maybe it's a silly question, but I'm feeling rusty with complex numbers...

Comment: Is there any restriction on $\theta$? For example, is $\theta$ rational?

Comment: Hint:
$$\frac{1-e^{(n+1)i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{ki\theta}.$$

Comment: @Servaes: theta is a generic real number. And please explain me what should i do with a generic geometric serie summation

Comment: @Servaes This is going exactly backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I've found is:

$$ \frac{e^{(n+1)i\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1} = $$

$$ \frac{\cos{(n+1)\theta} -1 +i\sin{(n+1)\theta}}{(\cos\theta - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \theta}(\cos \theta -1 -i\sin\theta)= $$

$$ \frac{\cos{n\theta} - \cos(n+1)\theta - \cos\theta + 1}{2-2\cos\theta} -i \frac{\sin{n\theta} - \sin(n+1)\theta + \sin\theta}{2-2\cos\theta}= $$

$$ \frac{\sin{(n+\frac{1}{2})\theta} + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}} +i \frac{\sin(n+1)\frac{\theta}{2} \sin(n\frac{\theta}{2})}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Now it's easy to distinguish real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 4):

For that very expression there's a trick to introduce $\alpha = \frac{\theta}{2}$ and noticing that

$$\frac{1- e^{i (n+1) \theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}} = \frac{e^{i (n+1)\alpha} (e^{i (n+1)\alpha} - e^{-i (n+1)\alpha})}{e^{i\alpha} (e^{i\alpha} - e^{-i\alpha})} = e^{in\alpha} \frac{\sin((n+1)\alpha)}{\sin \alpha}$$

I'll let you conclude...

Answer (score 1):

You have

$\sum_{k=0}^nz^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z},$

So

$\frac{1-{\mathrm e}^{i\theta(n+1)}}{1-{\mathrm e}^{i\theta}}=\sum_{k=0}^n{\mathrm e}^{i\theta k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(\theta k)+i\sum_{k=0}^n\sin(\theta k).$

Hence the real part is $\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(\theta k)$.

Answer (score -3):

**hint**: $$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$$, $$e^{(n+1)i\theta} = \cos(n+1)\theta+i\sin(n+1)\theta$$

Comment: Yep, I know... But after I use Euler's equality, I have a new fraction that I don't know how to handle

Comment: Rearrange and multiply a conjugation of the denominator.